# Why Visual Studio (2017; 15.7.5) don't let me change c++ keywords color

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can change the colour to a truckload of items in editor font & colors tool, except for the very pillar of (c++) keywords (looks like to apply to all of the flow-control keywords):

`return`; `if/else`; `break`; `switch/case`; `while/do`; `for`;

No matter the editor theme, there is no such selection (flow control keyword) in the tools dialogue so in dark theme, they are always displayed in freaking ugly red colour (on dark theme!).

In the dialogue, there are "keyword"; "user keyword" selection. But the shown colour is not Red.

google: I've tried to formulate in every query forms that my English skills can do, nothing is to be found about those specific keywords and colour (topics).

Anybody is experiencing the same issue?
Bugs with locale language on Windows 10 (Visual Studio 2017 15.7.?)? 
(Windows 10 locale is French. Changing it to English is not an option)

Thanks.

P.S.: Btw, in my humble opinion, that tools dialogue must be redone! It is a huge mess! Mixing everythings in the "font and colors section" is scary, overwhelming.

Comment: Changing `Keyword` item on Fonts and colors tab works fine for me.

Comment: I am starting to have a doubt. I do not have installed many extensions yet. But I am willing to reset and uninstall the extensions one-by-one to see the changes. (I love the rainbow brackets. I hope it is not that one that screws the editor on side-effects).

Answer (score 0):

Here. I found the culprit: This extension: "Viasfora" bypasses the colouring of flow control keywords. I will report it to whoever it is. Sad. I like so much this Rainbow Brackets extension.

Sorry for disturbing. Therefore, I think this issue might be useful to others in the same situation.

Comment: The culprit is ME. Viasfora has that feature but into the Viasfora options. Confusing, but not a bug.
Tools->Viasfora